# Gerrit will not push. Error: No common ancestry

Tags: git, gerrit

Trying to push to gerrit. Brings up no common ancestry.

```
nolan@nolan-pc:~/pac-man$ git push ssh://1KX2@review.pac-rom.com:29418/android_vendor_pac HEAD:refs/for/pac-6.0
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 6.63 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://1KX2@review.pac-rom.com:29418/android_vendor_pac
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/pac-6.0 (no common ancestry)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://1KX2@review.pac-rom.com:29418/android_vendor_pac'
```

Comment: Are you sure your HEAD is a downstream of the remote pac-6.0 branch? Its likely that your destination branch name also isn't correct.

Comment: Seems the HEAD is not developed from branch pac-6.0. Please have a check what the checked out revision is.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a long time, but in my case, I used automatic rebase from gerrit interface to resolve simple conflicts. Maybe this introduce some changes between my local repository and the server one.
I simply had to sync with git to get those updates.
Using the `git pull --rebase origin master` worked for me.

Comment: 这个同样适用于我：git pull --rebase origin master

Comment: 因为之前有别人提交过，但是我没有pull最新代码。

Comment: 还得是Stack Overflow啊。ｂ(￣▽￣)ｄ

Answer (score 4):

One case where this is solved "easily" is if you pushed to an entirely new repo and have no interest in any possibly old git history that brought your project code to the state it has now.

Then a solution is to start in a new folder, then clone the (empty) project from gerrit. This folder then have a common ancestry with this gerrit project. Then you could work to add your source files into this new folder using git add until satisfied,(that mundane work is the non-easy part) leaving out any old .git folder and finally try a push. This pushes your project onto gerrit with git history beginning from this point on.

Comment: This sort-of works, but I suspect most people want to find a way to combine the histories and allow a push of the result.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your local development history is totally independent of the development history of the pac-6.0 branch. They don't have a common ancestry.

See more info here:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-no-common-ancestry.html

Comment: This is a good diagnosis of the situation, but it would be better to offer a solution. How can the histories be combined?

Comment: The link (Gerrit documentation) offer a solution: "To fix the problem you should check your push specification and verify that you are pushing the commit to the correct project". Normally this is the issue in this situation. If the person (or someone else) had replied with more info then I could have tried to help more.

Comment: I had seen those docs in my first query, they weren't relevant. I was trying to import a project that had been hosted on GitHub into a Linux Foundation-managed repo. My notes and eventual solution are [here](https://trello.com/c/6oRyX4Ts/465-import-puppet-opendaylight-and-ansible-opendaylight-into-odl-managed-repos) if you'd like to incorporate them into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are pushing on incorrect branch . Use correct branch it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).