# Failed to push, Error - no common ancestry

Tags: gerrit

```
[root@vmc0162 git_repo]#  git push ssh://ogw@10.61.216.82:29418/Test HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 7983, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects:  19% (1429/7520)
Compressing objects: 100% (7520/7520), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7983/7983), 436.48 MiB | 13.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 7983 (delta 2584), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2584/2584)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://10.61.216.82:29418/Test
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (no common ancestry)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://ogw@10.61.216.82:29418/Test'
```

Comment: Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066069/gerrit-will-not-push-error-no-common-ancestry